# Comparison between Mobile Push Notification Services

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, backend

I'm investigating the existing providers for push notification service.
The goal is to simplify the backend of a mobile app and avoid to directly communicate with services like APNS or handle stuff like device tokens, etc.

Interesting (desired) features:

- send push notifications directly from the app (without going through a server)
- using custom criteria (e.g. a custom id) for selecting the recipient of a push notification

I've found the following services and I was wondering if anyone of you guys has ever used any of them:

- https://www.parse.com/
- http://www.pushapps.mobi/
- https://zeropush.com/
- https://boxcar.io/developer
- https://www.pushwoosh.com/
- https://gamethrive.com/
- http://quickblox.com/
- https://backendless.com/

Do you guys have any recommendation? In your opinion, which solution is the most appropriate for the use-case I mentioned?

Comment: You can also try https://onesignal.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the solutions I mentioned are quite good but require push notifications to be sent through a remote API, preferably from a server.

The only one that has all the features I need is Parse, which allows to send push notifications from the app and select target devices by custom fields.

Comment: I strongly apologize for the comment, but it does look as the original poster has asked the question about Parse and answered it by itself :) Among other Pushwoosh is the service that offers Control Panel to send pushes, not Remote API on its Free plan!

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer, I work on GameThrive, one of the services mentioned by the question asker)

Android & iOS devices have two methods of showing notifications to users when the app is not running.

1. Local Notifications (Or sometimes called Alarms for Android)
2. Remote Notifications

#### Local Notifications

Local notifications are a built in feature in iOS and Android, and you can use them without having any third party services involved.  There might be libraries available to make them easier to program and schedule, but no ongoing 3rd party service is necessary.

#### Remote Notifications

Remote Notifications require communication with the Apple or Google's servers (For iOS and Google Play Apps, respectively). This communication must be done from a server that either you or a 3rd party operate. This third party server keeps track of the identifiers of each device that might receive notifications, as well as communicates with Apple or Google's systems to send notifications.

Each of the services you mention has its own advantages and price differences. In the case of GameThrive, we've worked to make our systems inexpensive and easy to use, especially for small companies. Most of the services you mentioned support what you need including custom targeting, but some may cost more or require additional development on your part than others.

Answer (score 0):

We had just decided on Parse and finished a prototype when we rec'd this:

"We have a difficult announcement to make. Beginning today we're winding down the Parse service, and Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on January 28, 2017. We're proud that we've been able to help so many of you build great mobile apps, but we need to focus our resources elsewhere. "

Looks like ZeroPush is going down even sooner:
https://zeropush.com/
"Today, we are excited to announce that we have joined Twitter as part of Fabric. We’ll be working alongside the teams that brought you other great developer tools like Crashlytics, Digits, Beta, and Answers.

ZeroPush will remain available until January 31, 2016. "